# Serial connection over PuTTY and -m?

Tags: script, putty, serial

I am using a com port to connect to a device. I would like to run a script that does 3 commands for me.

Currently I'm trying to do "start putty.exe -load temp1 -m script.txt"

All of that is in the same directory. Putty opens with the saved config (temp1) but my script doesnt run. I want to say that -m only applies for SSH but I just wanted to be sure or see if anyone has any ideas of how to run scripts over serial.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running batch commands through PuTTY serial connection](https://superuser.com/questions/1310872/running-batch-commands-through-putty-serial-connection)